# Is there efficient Condition.wait() alternative with reliable timeout?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multithreading, wait

I ran into a problem with Python 3.8 implementation of `threading.Event.wait(timeout)` (which uses internally `threading.Condition.wait()`). The problem is described [here](https://bugs.python.org/issue41710) as a bug. If I understand it correctly, since underlying Lock uses non-monotonic time and thus it may happen, that timeout is shorter/longer, then specified.

Is there some alternative to `Condition.wait()`, which would not suffer from time change, when timeout is used and which is reasonably effective (CPU is not overloaded, like in simple busy waiting)?

Comment: What are you looking for?  The statement "Is there some alternative to this, which would not suffer from this and is more effective, then busy-waiting? Some kind of semi-busy waiting?" isn't helpful in trying to determine what you want

Comment: @itprorh66 You are right, the question was poorly written. I tried to rewrite it to be more clear and specific.

Comment: Okay, so since the ```conditon.wait()``` command doesn't provide an exact time delay but simply an approximation, you are looking for a means to implement the functionality of ```threading>Event.wailt(timeout)``` that results in an exact/repeatable time delay.  Is this correct?

Comment: Actually, I don't necessarily need it to be exact (my target is +-10ms precision), however, I need reliability in this range. For the `threading.Event.wait(timeout)`, the error is unbounded (see example file [here](https://bugs.python.org/issue41710), where you basically specify the error).